# random numbers with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

someone can help me with this little problem. I am trying to visualize on a screen four random numbers completely on the right side on the screen, but separated one of each other some space and I need to change the size of each number.
I know the "font" is used to change the size ofa text of the label but this also change the size of the label.
To conclude, I want to know **how can I put random numbers of different sizes on the right side on my screen?**

```
from Tkinter import *
import math
from random import randrange

number=Tk()
number.geometry("1308x720")
number.config(bg="black")
ECG=randrange(0,1000)
SP=randrange(0,1000)
PLES=randrange(0,1000)
show=randrange(0,1000)
c1=StringVar();c2=StringVar();c3=StringVar();c4=StringVar()
c1.set(ECG);c2.set(SP);c3.set(PLES);c4.set(show)
valor_c1=Label(number,textvariable=c1,width=3,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="green").grid(row=0,column=2)
valor_c2=Label(number,textvariable=c2,width=3,height=1,fg="blue",anchor="ne",bg="snow").grid(row=4,column=2)
valor_c3=Label(number,textvariable=c3,width=3,height=1,fg="cyan",anchor="ne",bg="grey").grid(row=8,column=2)
valor_c4=Label(number,textvariable=c4,width=3,height=1,fg="gold",anchor="ne",bg="blue").grid(row=16,column=2)
number.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `width` option according to the random values. And specify `sticky=E` (E=East, right side) to the `grid` call.

```
Label(number,textvariable=c1,width=int(c1.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="green").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
Label(number,textvariable=c2,width=int(c2.get())//10,height=1,fg="blue",anchor="ne",bg="snow").grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=E)
Label(number,textvariable=c3,width=int(c3.get())//10,height=1,fg="cyan",anchor="ne",bg="grey").grid(row=8,column=2, sticky=E)
Label(number,textvariable=c4,width=int(c4.get())//10,height=1,fg="gold",anchor="ne",bg="blue").grid(row=16,column=2, sticky=E)
```

BTW, you're assign the return value of the `grid`. `grid` returns nothing; So the `valor_c*` are all `None`.

[image]

Also add the following line to align the cells to right of the screen (by making the column 2 grow, see [`grid_columnconfigure`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method)):

```
number.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

[image]

Comment: @rpi-uts, Please post a separated question.

Comment: the other post call "separate random numbers in tkinter"

Comment: @rpi-uts, The code in the new answer make a cell all in the same row, column.